# How to read .Net web service in PHP?

Tags: php, .net, web-services

I have successfully read WSDL form SoapClient. I tried following to pass value to web method and read results:

```
 $client = new SoapClient("restaurant.asmx?wsdl");
 $param = array('search_keywords'=>$search_text); 
 $result =  $client->__soapCall('getRestaurantsASP',$param);
 print_r($result);
```

I got this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [soap:Server]
System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> 
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name 'basic_info_table'. at 
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean   
breakConnection) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException 
exception, Boolean breakConnection) at 
System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning() at 
System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, 
SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject 
stateObj) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ConsumeMetaData() at 
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData() at 
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior 
runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) at 
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, 
RunBehavior runBehavior in E:\webareas\gs937\aspservice.php on line 73
```

How can I send parameters to web method and retrieve values?

Comment: Looks like a problem on the server side to me that, specifically a problem with an SQL query.

Comment: but when i test it using test page, it returns value fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add:

```
<webServices>
<protocols>
  <add name="HttpGet"/>
  <add name="HttpPost"/>
  <add name="HttpSoap"/>
</protocols>
</webServices>
```

in Web.config file to get things working.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by DaveRandom, problem seems to be in service itself rather problem is in SQL query used for service.

Try using SoapUI (you can download it from http://sourceforge.net/projects/soapui/files/) and execute the service method from there.

SoapUI is a neutral client to test the webservices.

Hope it will help.